# Why is array_unique not working in this situation

Tags: php

I have a column that contain integer values. I join all columns by doing

```
"SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(column) AS column"
```

Then I build an array doing

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $employees[] = $row['column'];
    }
```

print_r($employees) returns Array ( [0] => 1,2,3,4,68,25,1 )

So I want to remove the duplicate 1 and for that I use `array_unique`

```
print_r(array_unique($employees));
```

This still brings back Array ( [0] => 1,2,3,4,68,25,1 )

What am I doing wrong here

Comment: `1,2,3,4,68,25,1` is considered as string

Comment: Because the numbers aren't actually numbers but a large string.

Comment: Of course, I need to explode it. Thanks. You can now downvote the dumb question

Comment: It's a well asked question, so no worries. Voted to close due to typo, as you seem to know what you're doing.

Comment: Yeah, felt so silly when I saw the first two comments. Let's close it

Comment: @Loek Even if this is kind of a silly question, it may help future visitors. Not sure if there is a dupe though

Comment: @seankonig I think this question may help future visitors. I bet there are people that don't realize a comma separated string is not the same as an array. Though there may be a duplicate, not sure

Comment: I suppose, it is a little silly though. I will accept your answer as soon as I can though. Thanks man

Comment: @seankonig The way I see it, it doesn't really matter how "silly" a question is. This is a well-asked question and if _you_ forgot you had to convert that to an array, there are definitely other people that may have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to use `array_unique()` on a string, which won't really do anything.

You can break this string into an array by using the [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function.

```
$unique = array_unique(explode(',', $employees[0]);
```

Alternatively, you could just check inside your loop if a value has already been put into an array using [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    if(!in_array($row['column'], $employees)) {
        $employees[] = $row['column'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution at SQL side:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT column) AS column
```

if you want an ordered list:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column ORDER BY Column
```

and then store all rows by

```
while(...) $employees[] = $row['column'];
```

Comment: Your answer is correct (and better) if the values are stored in separate rows, but my answer stands for if it is stored as a string. But I think saying that using `explode()` and `array_unique()` together is "too much overhead", is really focusing on a micro-optimization at best (given not gigantic datasets)

Comment: With GROUP_CONCAT you can run in size limits.

Comment: Thanks, I really am working with small chunks of data, but this is even cleaner. I will keep this in mind though

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `array_map` function. And map all value with `intdiv` function

```
$employees = array_unique(array_map("intdiv", $employees));
print_r($employees);
```